# disable next button in a particular tour in zurb jquery joyride

Tags: jquery, zurb-joyride

I am using http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

to create a guided tutorial. I need to exclude next button in one of those tutorial. I did add `data-options="nextButton:false;"` in `<li>` tag of that tutorial but still next button is visible. I am posting all relevant codes.

```
$('#joyRideTipContent')
            .joyride(
                    {
                        autoStart : true,
                        modal : true,
                        nextButton : true,
                        expose : false,
                        nubPosition : 'auto',
                        tipContainer : 'body',
                        tipAnimation : 'fade',

                    });
```

and in `li`

`<li data-id="eleId" data-text="Next: Blah Blah" data-options="nextButton:false;">`

Comment: Apply an id to li and then disable next button as $('#li_id').joyride(
                    {                        
                        nextButton : false                       

                    });

Comment: its not working @Rider. Is their any other way to do ??

Answer (score 1):

I added a checkbox that says someone agrees before displaying the next button.  Finds the div of the current step based on the [index] and then locates it's Next link to change the CSS.

Step HTML:  Accept

```
this.preStepCallback = function (index) {
    $('div[data-index="' + index + '" ]').find('a:contains("Next")').css({"display":"none"});

    $('input:checkbox').live('change', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('div[data-index="' + index + '" ]').find('a:contains("Next")').css({"display":""});
        } else {
        $('div[data-index="' + index + '" ]').find('a:contains("Next")').css({"display":"none"});
        }
    });
}
```